# Excel stops import of CSV file when reaching quotes

Tags: excel, csv, import, quotes, partial

The csv file when opened in notepad looks like:

```
Name,Jun 13,Jun 20,Jun 27,Jul 4,Jul 11,Jul 18,Jul 25,Aug 1,Aug 8,Aug 15
LastName"," FirstName,40,40,0,8,0,0,0,8,0,0
LastName"," FirstName,32,40,40,20,12,12,12,8,0,0
LastName"," FirstName,40,40,40,48,40,40,40,40,24,0
```

However, when opening in excel it cuts off at the first quotation mark and stops the import. In excel it looks like:

```
Name,Jun 13,Jun 20,Jun 27,Jul 4,Jul 11,Jul 18,Jul 25,Aug 1,Aug 8,Aug 15
LastName"
```

My understanding is that when you want to have a comma escaped in CSV, you 
surround it with double quotes, which I did because I want the first name and last name to be in the same cell. I don't want to change anything to the local excel settings because this will be a file that will be downloaded from a website, so having every user change settings would not be ideal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to:

```
Name,Jun 13,Jun 20,Jun 27,Jul 4,Jul 11,Jul 18,Jul 25,Aug 1,Aug 8,Aug 15
"LastName, FirstName",40,40,0,8,0,0,0,8,0,0
"LastName, FirstName",32,40,40,20,12,12,12,8,0,0
"LastName, FirstName",40,40,40,48,40,40,40,40,24,0
```

Here is a spec on how to handle different characters in CSV format:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180